# ReferenceError when using require

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, datetimepicker, require

I'm trying to create a wrapper as a React component for [this DateTimePicker jQuery plugin](https://gijgo.com/datepicker). So far it's working, but I'm trying to set it's locale and to do that I need to import a specific file from the library.

I'm doing so at `require('gijgo/js/messages/messages.pt-br')`, however it throws an error `ReferenceError: gj is not defined`. The object `gj` is imported at `require('gijgo/js/gijgo');` and I already tried doing something like this:

```
const gj = require('gijgo/js/gijgo');
window.gj = gj;
require('gijgo/js/messages/messages.pt-br')
```

Just like I did to import jQuery (the library gijgo uses it), but it didn't work.

This is my whole code:

```
import React from "react"
import $ from 'jquery'
import 'bootstrap';
import { TextInput } from '../Form/Form'

window.jQuery = $;
window.$ = $;
require('gijgo/js/gijgo');
require('gijgo/js/messages/messages.pt-br')
require('gijgo/css/gijgo.css');

export default class DateTimePicker extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.$dateTimePicker = $(this.dateTimePicker);
    this.$dateTimePicker.on("change", this.props.onChange);
    this.$dateTimePicker.datetimepicker({
      locale: 'pt-br',
      uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4',
      format: 'dd-mm-yyyy HH:MM',
      modal: true,
      footer: true
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.$dateTimePicker.destroy("datetimepicker");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <TextInput {...this.props} ref={dateTimePicker => this.dateTimePicker = dateTimePicker}/>
    )
  }
}
```

Is there a way to "require something after something else fully loaded?". Am I missing something?

Note 1: yes, I know jQuery + React = bad, but I like this component and I'm porting an old project to React that uses this library, so I figure it would be nice to have it as a React component. My main goal however, is to have *some* Date Time Picker component that looks like gijgo's and works with React, so I'm open to suggestions.

Note 2: I'm using gijgo through npm (`npm install gijgo --save`)

**Update 1**

Note 3: I'm kinda new at React JS development and I'm not *quite* sure what I'm using for bundling, but the script that runs when I run `npm start` or `yarn start` is `react-scripts start`. Also, the error also shows `__webpack_require__` and

```
  779 | };
  780 | 
  781 | // Execute the module function
> 782 | modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  783 | 
  784 | // Flag the module as loaded
  785 | module.l = true;
```

**Update 2**

I've tried creating a separate file to import jQuery and setting it globally, so I could stop using `require` and use `import` instead. Still, I keep getting the same error.

Here's my `jQuery.js` file:

```
import jquery from 'jquery';
global.$= jquery;
global.jQuery = jquery;
```

and here's my updated imports:

```
(...)
import '../jQuery'
import 'gijgo/js/gijgo'
import 'gijgo/js/messages/messages.pt-br'
import 'gijgo/css/gijgo.css'
(...)
```

**Update 3**

It didn't work when I tried using gijgo from `<script>`, it said `datetimepicker` is not recognized. I must be doing something wrong, as I'm having a hard time trying to understand how to mix jQuery with React. I think gijgo is a good library and everything. But for this particular case I actually decided to use [DateTimePicker from material-ui/pickers](https://material-ui-pickers.dev/api/DateTimePicker).

Comment: How are you bundling this? Webpack? Rollup? Browserify? `require()` is part of CommonJS, which does not exist in the browser. Similarly, support for ES6 modules is very limited, and scripts have to be specially marked to be parsed as ES6 modules. Can you [edit] your question to clarify how you're dealing with some of these points?

Comment: Hi! I've (shamefully) updated my question

Comment: Oh, you're using [create react app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/README.md), or "CRA", which uses Webpack under the hood. Thank you, that is definitely useful information for answering your question.

Comment: What happens when you change `require('gijgo/js/gijgo');
require('gijgo/js/messages/messages.pt-br');
require('gijgo/css/gijgo.css');` to `import 'gijgo/js/gijgo';
 import 'gijgo/js/messages/messages.pt-br';
import 'gijgo/css/gijgo.css';`?

Comment: It says that "jQuery is not defined". This is why I am setting jQuery at window and using require for importing gijgo.

Comment: Might try using `global.jQuery = $; global.$= $;`. `global` should be transformed by Webpack to `window`, if I remember correctly. Put those statements in a separate file that you `import` before importing `gijgo` like I suggested in the above comment, to guarantee they're exposed to the global namespace before the widgets are loaded.

Comment: I updated my question with the attempt, but I keep getting the same error. It does help for importing jQuery tho, so it's a plus :)

Comment: Well, you followed my advice exactly correct, I apologize my suggestion didn't solve the problem. I'll try to reproduce it myself later when I have time and try to come up with a solution I know works, unless someone else comes along and posts in the meantime.

Comment: No need to apologize, you're being helpful already! I'll keep looking for solutions aswell, and if you come up with one, I'm looking forward to try it :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199706/discussion-between-mari-faleiros-and-patrick-roberts).

Comment: ignore my answer. The problem was much simpler. `gijgo` is not module-aware, so you can't `import` them. You'll have to include them as `<script>`s, and consequently, include jQuery as a `<script>` above as well.

Comment: Notice that `gijgo/js/gijgo.js` declares `var gj = {};` but never exposes it to the global namespace. It assumes it's being included as a `<script>`, which would cause the `var` declaration to become a property of the `window` object, while ES6 modules are encapsulated in IIFEs that prevent `var` declarations from being exposed to `window`.

Comment: Oh that makes sense (and btw, it wasn't me who downvoted your answer, jic you were wondering). I'll try to use gijgo as a ```<script>``` then. Thank you!